# Signed in with IP Address Before Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science, screen-scraping

I've been trying to **scrape** the website "https://www.china-data-online.com/member/hynbefore2003/hyntshowjj.asp?hy=0610&code=A01", which requires IP address sign-in before I have access to it. I have the correct IP address right now and have no trouble opening it in my browser, but when I do web scraping on it, it does not recognize the IP address and require me to refresh the front page: "https://www.china-data-online.com/". I've tried to use Selenium to refresh the page before I do the web scraping, but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
raw_industry_link = soup.findAll('a', class_="bluelink")
for i in raw_industry_link:
    if i.attrs['href'][-4] in '0123456789': #Select the page with 4-digit code
        new_url = url+'hyntshowjj.asp?hy='+i.attrs['href'][-4:]+'&code=A01'
        r = requests.post(new_url, {'ayear':1999})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: I could open the front page with Python and have it recognizing my IP address with no problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running this script on your local machine, this website might know that you're automating the access to it. Try insert Headers in your request:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
raw_industry_link = soup.findAll('a', class_="bluelink")
for i in raw_industry_link:
    if i.attrs['href'][-4] in '0123456789': #Select the page with 4-digit code
        new_url = url+'hyntshowjj.asp?hy='+i.attrs['href'][-4:]+'&code=A01'
        r = requests.post(new_url, {'ayear':1999})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thank you! But I think the problem is that the website is a database that I can automatically login with my school IP address, but when I run the python script, it is not recognizing the IP address anymore.  I've tried to look at a few tutorials when they require a login information, but they don't apply to my case because there is no user id and password.

Comment: You're Python script can't (someone corrects me if I am wrong) change you're IP address when you doing some network I/O. If you can't do this, I believe that the website is blocking you somehow. You may want to check for the Response Headers and edit your question with it. This will help us and you to see what is happening when you are automating the access to the website